# Unwanted dots and arrows appearing in TeXnic center

Tags: errors

I am facing a strange problem. Whenever I type something in LaTeX, some unwanted dots and arrows appear whenever I hit space bar and enter respectively.

For example, when want to write

Let $f$ be an entire function. It shows like this

Let. $f$. be. an. enitre. function.

Similarly,  symbols like $\rightarrow$ are appearing whenever I hit enter

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: ? You do not type anything in LaTeX, you use a text editor to prepare the input code for LaTeX. So this question is not clear unless you tell us which editor you are using, and what's the exact configuration (maybe you are using an editor that shows explicit space characters?)

Comment: you have tagged this errors but I see no indication that there is any error here. Since you are describing the source file, latex is not involved. You have not said what editor you are using but it sounds like you have enabled a setting so that it marks invisible characters in teh edit view (in a way that presumably does not affect teh actual file that is passed to latex)

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot to mention that  I am using TeXnic center as TeX editor.